# Форма ввода для любых символов

Tags: php, javascript, html

Вопрос: мне нужно сделать поле для ввода текста (типа как в input text), чтобы при этом туда можно было записывать абсолютно любые символы, html-тэги, кавычки и тому подобное. И после нажатия submit всё это отправлялось в mysql-таблицу без изменений.

Какой есть наиболее простой способ для этого? Спасибо.

Comment: А что смущает? Что не вызывает затруднение?

Comment: чем не устраивают обычные поля input или textarea? и еще вопрос: а вы это хотите на публичный сайт выложить?

Comment: в обычную html форму если ввести кавычки и тэги, то она может глючит и отправлять неполные данные)
Думаю, тут нужен javascript или что-то такое.

Comment: Форма ввода-то тут причем, почему она должна глючить? Cпец.символы экранируйте при записи в базу и все будет добавляться.

Comment: нет, это проект для личного пользования.

Comment: типа так string quotemeta ( string $str )?
спасибо. Я не знал про экранирование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текстовое поле input и текстовая область textarea позволяют вводить любые символы. Проблемы могут быть только при записи в базу данных и при повторном редактировании данных.

1.Если вы пользуетесь каким-нибудь современным расширением, например, PDO вам не требуется ничего специально экранировать, так как вы вставляете присланный текст через плейсхолдеры, как есть, строкой

```
<?php
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
      'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
      'root',
      '',
      [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl
              VALUES (NULL, :name)";
    $news = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $news->execute(['name' => $_POST['name']]);

    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    Имя: <input type="text" name="name" value=""><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Записать">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

2.Проблемы могут быть, если вы выводите текст на редактирование или подставляете только что введенный текст в атрибут `value` текстового поля или между тэгами `<textarea>` и `</textarea>`. В этом случае чтобы избежать искажения текст пропускают через функцию `htmlspecialchars()`, которая преобразует все интерпретируемые символы в HTML-безопасную форму

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    Имя: <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Записать">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё именно так, как вы описали. Я вывожу только что введенный текст на редактирование через value. Я пропустил текст через htmlspecialchars(), всё стало работать. Всё, кроме одиночных кавычек. Это в принципе не так страшно, но их по прежнему вводить нельзя почему-то.

Comment: @KirillVolkov, Добавьте в htmlspecialchars() второй параметр ENT_QUOTES, чтобы одиночные кавычки тоже преобразовывались.